# How many OS crashes a day are normal?

Tags: diagnostics, nokia-lumia-730

I bought a Lumia 730 with WP 8.1 Update and Nokia Denim five days ago.

Every day the OS crashes at least twice a day during different operations and sometimes even when I don't actively use the phone. It reboots and things are okay again.

I'm new to Windows Phone, but I assume this is not normal?

Are there any event logs I can access to find out more about these crashes?

Or can I assume this is a hardware problem and should I consider returning the phone?

Comment: I had several Lumias in the past two years and I still have two, I do not remember having a single crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my question, zero OS crashes are normal.

Blue screens on Desktop Windows usually happen because of faulty hardware or badly written third party drivers.

I don't think there are many third party drivers on Windows Phone, but there is one piece of external hardware the Micro-SD card.

So I moved all apps and data from the SD card to the internal memory and haven't experienced any crashes since.

In my case the card was a 32GB Sony card which I had used before in a camera without problems. I will get a new card and try again.

Comment: You could first try formatting your SD card, maybe it's just a filesystem problem.

Comment: Which was the class of the card? My daughter has a 32GB class 10 works flawless.

Comment: @VitorCanova - Mine was also a Class 10

Comment: @Indrek - I formatted (not quick format) the card in Windows and moved the Apps back onto it. After a few days I haven't had any crashes yet.

Answer (score 4):

Your phone should not crash at all - Windows Phone is usually a rather stable OS. Try doing a hard reset before returning it - if that does not help get a replacement phone.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, not normal from the array of Windows Phones I have owned. I would take the phone back to where I purchased it and get a new one

Answer (score -1):

I've had one every six months maybe.  That would work out to .0054795